# String split in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I'm new to Visual Basic .net and I would like some help doing this:

I'm receiving these strings:

```
!re=.id=*10000AF=name=Down-PBX=parent=Down=packet-mark=pack_pbx=limit-at=256000=queue=PCQ_Down=priority=1=max-limit=512000=burst-limit=0=burst-threshold=0=burst-time=00:00:00=invalid=false=disabled=true=comment=PBX

!re=.id=*10000B0=name=Up-PBX=parent=Up=packet-mark=pack_pbx=limit-at=256000=queue=PCQ_Up=priority=1=max-limit=512000=burst-limit=0=burst-threshold=0=burst-time=00:00:00=invalid=true=disabled=true=comment=PBX

!re=.id=*10000C7=name=Down_Mauro=parent=Down=packet-mark==limit-at=315000=priority=8=max-limit=5000000=burst-limit=0=burst-threshold=0=burst-time=00:00:00=invalid=false=disabled=true
```

(Only pasted 3 but there are many more)

And I have them in a String Array called tree().

What I want to do is a function that returns new Array, I guess a multidimensional one, that separates everything between the "=", starting from "name". Like this:

```
Down-PBX, Down, pack_pbx, 256000, PCQ-DOWN, etc
Up-PBX, UP, pack_pbx, 256000, etc
```

And so on.

Any help wil be really appreciated!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the first value you want is always the 5th member of the array, and you wish to return every 2nd value in the array after that:

```
Private Function GetParts(source As String) As String()
    Dim Parts As String() = source.Split(New Char() {"="C})

    Dim Items As New List(Of String)()
    For i As Integer = 4 To Parts.Length - 1 Step 2
        Items.Add(Parts(i))
    Next

    Return Items.ToArray()
End Function
```

Essentially, you start at the 5th part of of the split string, and then iterate every 2nd element after that, adding each one to a generic list of strings.  You then return this as an array of string.

I do not have a copy of VB here so it may not work 100%, but it should give you the general gist of what you are trying to achieve.  I wrote it in C# and then attempted to convert it to VB.Net (fingers crossed!).

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy:

```
Dim output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("name=") + 5) _
                  .Split("="c) _
                  .Where(Function(e, i) i Mod 2 = 0) _
                  .ToArray()
```

`output` content:

```
Down-PBX
Down
pack_pbx
256000
PCQ_Down
1
512000
0
0
00:00:00
false
true
PBX
```

Multidimensional version:

```
Dim input() As String = {
    "!re=.id=*10000AF=name=Down-PBX=parent=Down=packet-mark=pack_pbx=limit-at=256000=queue=PCQ_Down=priority=1=max-limit=512000=burst-limit=0=burst-threshold=0=burst-time=00:00:00=invalid=false=disabled=true=comment=PBX",
    "!re=.id=*10000B0=name=Up-PBX=parent=Up=packet-mark=pack_pbx=limit-at=256000=queue=PCQ_Up=priority=1=max-limit=512000=burst-limit=0=burst-threshold=0=burst-time=00:00:00=invalid=true=disabled=true=comment=PBX",
    "!re=.id=*10000C7=name=Down_Mauro=parent=Down=packet-mark==limit-at=315000=priority=8=max-limit=5000000=burst-limit=0=burst-threshold=0=burst-time=00:00:00=invalid=false=disabled=true"
}

Dim output = input.Select(Function(i) i.Substring(i.IndexOf("name=") + 5) _
                                       .Split("="c) _
                                       .Where(Function(e, idx) idx Mod 2 = 0) _
                                       .ToArray()) _
                  .ToArray()
```

`output` is `String()()` here.

Comment: I'm getting this error:
Error 2 Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement.

Comment: Now it says Error 2 'Select' is not a member of 'System.Array'. :(

Comment: Add `Imports System.Linq` at the top of your file.

Comment: Now i got this: System.NullReferenceException in .ToArray()) _ and something about reference to an object not established as an instance of an object